# Excluding an item from a list where an element matches an element from another list of a different type

Tags: c#

I have the following populated lists:

```
List<Item> Items
List<long> QueueID
```

Where Item is this:

```
public Class Item
{
long QueueID    
....
}
```

I need to make a new List of Items that excludes Items with QueueIDs that are in the other List.

I'm trying this but the compiler doesn't like it.

```
var result = Items.Where(x => !QueueID.Exists(x => x.QueueID));
```

Comment: I recommend using a Hashet<long> to store the ids if you want out of the box uniqueness + faster lookups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this approach using [`List.Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.contains?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
List<Item> resultList = Items.Where(x => !QueueID.Contains(x.QueueID)).ToList();
```